# Running the Flash Player over long time period

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi I'm looking into the issues to expect if the Flash Player (version 10) is run over a long period of time, say 24+ hours.

I know that the player has issues with not performing garbage collection properly, and that the weak listener system is buggy.

I plan on having the flash app started/monitored using a watchdog/sentinal app written in C/C++/C#. So I plan on refreshing the app periodically.

Does anyone have recommended practices for running a flash player over that sort of time scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory leaks are probably the worst. If you manage to make an app run on a 100% stable memory level for 1 hour it should also run for 24 hour and more (if its activity is stable as well).
Flex's profiler is nice to look up for leaks and uncollected items ...

Answer (score 1):

I think, you want to make an application run a long time not easily and not difficult. You must always free memory at interval 300ms ( use LocalConnection).